# Authorize existing app to different account without authorize page

Tags: twitter

I created an app on one twitter account. I would like to authorise that same app on a different account.

[FAQ on how to authorise apps](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76052) says `On the website of the application you want to connect, find the button/link asking you to connect your Twitter account`. But I haven't built said site/page.

How can I auth this app on the second account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the OAuth Authentication Flow process.
To do so, you first need to request an authentication link from your `Consumer Key` and `Consumer Secret` using `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token` (doc : https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/request_token).

When you receive a callback or a code, you can use them to execute a second query that is `https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token` as described at https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/reference/post/oauth/access_token. You will want to use the `oauth_verifier` parameter.

Remember that authentication in Twitter is not an easy process and you should read more about it on Twitter (https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged) or use a library that will do that for you.